# Two queries faster than than one?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have a table with columns:

```
CREATE TABLE aggregates (
    a VARHCAR,
    b VARCHAR,
    c VARCHAR,
    metric INT
    KEY test (a, b, c, metric)
);
```

If I do a query like:

```
SELECT b, c, SUM(metric) metric
FROM aggregates
WHERE a IN ('a', 'couple', 'of', 'values')
GROUP BY b, c
ORDER BY b, c
```

The query takes 10 seconds, explain is:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aggregates | range | test          | test | 767     | NULL | 582383 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I also group by/order by column a, so it doesn't need temporary/filesort, but then do the same thing in another query myself:

```
SELECT b, c, SUM(metric) metric
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM(metric) metric
    FROM aggregates
    WHERE a IN ('a', 'couple', 'of', 'values')
    GROUP BY a, b, c
    ORDER BY a, b, c
) t
GROUP BY b, c
ORDER BY b, c
```

The query takes 1 second and the explain is:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    252 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | aggregates | range | test          | test | 767     | NULL | 582383 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Why is this? Why is it faster if I do the grouping in a separate, outer query, instead of it just doing it all in one?

Comment: Do the two queries show same results? Have you forgotten `metric` in the 2nd query?

Comment: This IMHO most likely has to do with how MySQL is implemented and might not work like this on other DB engines.

Comment: Are you sure the performance difference isn't just database caching?

Comment: The second query would raise error in MySQL - and any other RDBMS. Soemthing went wrong during "copy-paste-changeNames".

Comment: ypercube: Yes, same results. Sorry, I forgot metric while simplifying. It is there, and I'll add it.

Comment: This is due to caching probably, as Nick mentioned. Please add in th equestion what indexes you have.

Comment: The key being used (test) is the one in the CREATE TABLE. I also have others, but they're not used here.

Comment: Unrelated but you don't have to state `ORDER BY b,c` when you `GROUP BY b,c` in MySQL.

Comment: Just run the 1st query again (and again). Does it always run in 10 seconds? Or it comes down to 1 second the 2nd or 3rd time you run it? (Or even less)?

Comment: Regarding caching: On a freshly rebooted server, executing first query #2, then query #1, the second query is still much faster.

Answer (score 2):

The way SQL works is the less data you have at each step the faster the query will perform.
Because you are doing the grouping in the inner query first you are getting rid of a lot of data that the outside query no longer needs to process.

[SQL optimisation](http://componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/increasesqlperformance.htm) should answer some of your questions. But the most important thing to remember is the more things you can eliminate early on in the query, the faster the query will run.

There is also a part of the database that tries different ways to run a query. This part of the server will most of the time choose the fastest path, but being more specific in your queries can really help it along.
More on that on this page: [Readings In Database Systems](http://redbook.cs.berkeley.edu/redbook3/lec7.html)

Looking at your explain it seems the filesort on such a huge number of rows is probably hurting the query a lot. since the rows in the primary query (second query's outer scope) will be working off an in memory table.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the index is used to find matching records, but cannot be used to sort as you do not include the leftmost column in the group/order by clauses. I would be interested to see both queries profiles:

> set profiling =1;
>
> run query 1;
>
> run query 2;
>
> show profile for query 1;
>
> show profile for query 2;

Comment: Interesting...: http://pastebin.com/fDJhPe4x  (first one is the slow one, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

**** Edited: Not good answer since I didn't see the where part.

I think it's simply that on the second query MySQL is using an index and the first is not.
If you create an index like `(b, c, metric)` I'm pretty sure the first query is going to be faster than the second.

Edited to be more verbose:

First query:

- There is not a good index to perform the query.
- The test index is on (a,b,c,metric) and you need a index on (b,c) ((b,c,metric) would be good also)
- Maybe MySQL is using test index, but is not a good index so is like full scan the table.

Second query:

- Is using the index (a,b,c)
- On second instance is performing a non index query but with less data than the first query.

Comment: Both queries are using the `test` index, as the EXPLAIN output shows.

Comment: I don't trust too much on the EXPLAIN. The index start on "a" column so I don't see how can apply to a group by without "a" column. Results confirm my theory :)
(Maybe is using the index but it is using it wrongly)

Comment: See here for how the index can be used in such a `GROUP BY` (Tight index scan): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: You are right, I didn't put attention on the where clause...
I think in the link you paste is the answer: Loose index scan is "The most efficient way to process GROUP BY". So changing `GROUP BY b, c` by `GROUP BY a, b, c` is probably faster.

Comment: I thought that too, but loose index scan cannot be used when there is `SUM()`. Only with `MIN()` and `MAX()`. So, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiousity, can you try this version?:

```
SELECT b, c, SUM(metric) metric
FROM aggregates
WHERE a = 'some-value'
GROUP BY b, c
```

and this one:

```
SELECT b, c, metric
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM(metric) metric
    FROM aggregates
    WHERE a = 'some-value'
    GROUP BY a, b, c
) t
ORDER BY b, c
```

and this:

```
SELECT b, c, SUM(metric) metric
FROM aggregates
WHERE a = 'some-value'
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

Comment: First one: same (slow) speed, second one: fast (but of course, just one row), third one: fast (but of course, more rows)

Comment: Fwiw, grouping by (a, b, c) returns 252 rows, by (b, c) returns 83.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how this can happen. You are obviously not telling us the whole story or you are not translating these queries correctly. I can't see how the first or second query would return 1 row.

Comment: I didn't say first one returned only 1 row, but you're right, I translated the second one incorrectly. We all make mistakes :) (and yes, of course, I am not telling the whole story and am simplifying the queries here a lot).

Comment: There's more rows, because I'm not doing a = 'some-value', but a IN (...). This is certainly relevant and I fear I might have omitted too much. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. `a = @somevalue` is different than `a IN (list of values)`. I would conclude that in your query#1 the index is used but without a tight index scan. You can try (your query#1) with a `(b,c,a,metric)` index.

Comment: Or keep my #2 (changing the `=` to `IN`). It's useless to have an `ORDER BY` in a subquery, unless you use `LIMIT`. And no need to group again in the wrapping query.

Comment: You do have to group again, otherwise you get multiple (b,c) pairs (because of IN). A (b,c,a,metric) index isn't used unless I force it, and even then it goes through all rows and is slow...